# Laravel missing required parameters on destroy route

Tags: php, laravel

I've just created a new project something like todo list in Laravel. When I try to do simple deleting I get this error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: destroy] [URI: {}]. (View: C:...\resources\views\index.blade.php)

Here is part of code from **index.blade.php**:

```
@if($todos)
    <ol>
       @foreach($todos as $todo)
           <li>{{ $todo->todo }}</li>
            <form action="" method="post">
                @csrf
                @method('Delete')
                <a href="{{ route('destroy', ['id' => $todo->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger">x</a>
            </form>
       @endforeach
    </ol>
@endif
```

so I am just checking if there is anything, if not, then don't show list.

Part of code from **controller**:

```
public function index()
    {
        $todos = Todo::all();
        return view('index', ['todos' => $todos]);
    }


public function destroy($id)
{
    Todo::findOrFail($id)->delete();
}
```

and line of code from **web.php**:

```
Route::resource('/', 'TodosController');
```

This is so basic and it is making me crazy because I can't figure out what is causing this error. Seems like everything is good.

Comment: `php artisan route:list` and make sure that route name is destroy

Comment: They generally look like  "todo.destroy" or "todos.destroy".

Comment: https://prnt.sc/rnqyhc

It is just destroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not 100% certain, but try updating your resource route declaration to:

```
Route::resource('todos', 'TodosController');
```

and changing your link to

```
<a href="{{ route('todos.destroy', ['todo' => $todo->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger">x</a>
```

In the docs here, https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters

They describe the routes as being created like:

**Actions Handled By Resource Controller**

> DELETE    /photos/{photo} destroy photos.destroy

Comment: this does not help :3

Comment: @SeadSilajdzic can you show us the output of `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: @SeadSilajdzic If the selected answer still isnt quite what you need, please see my update above.NOTE this will update all the urls to have a /todos prefix but this is how it should be for everything to work properly. You may also need the `@method('DELETE')` from Qirel's answer to make the verb correct

Comment: ty so much hahah this part made it work

needed to change in Route::resource('/', ...) to Route::resource('todos', ...) , at first it was strange to me why there is no any uri at route:list but now i know. At least I have learned something new :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually submit your form. You just click on a link, so you in essence make a GET request, and not a POST request.

You need to send it through a form.

```
@foreach($todos as $todo)
    <li>{{ $todo->todo }}</li>

    <form action="{{ route('destroy', $todo->id) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="x" />
    </form>
@endforeach
```

Having an inline form like that can appear a bit weird, so you can instead put the button outside, and submit your form on click.

```
@foreach($todos as $todo)
    <li>
        {{ $todo->todo }}
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" 
           onclick="event.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById('todo-destroy-{{ $todo->id }}').submit();">x</a>
    </li>

    <form action="{{ route('destroy', $todo->id) }}" method="POST" id="todo-destroy-{{ $todo->id }}">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
    </form>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hmm, wouldnt that produces a "Method not allowed" error though?

Comment: It should, which suggests that there's also a GET route for `/destroy` (which, imo, is bad).

Comment: Ah, that could be, and if so, completely agree, plus, the route the OP wants is surely `todos.destroy` or similar and not just `destroy`,.... unless they've manually done some weird stuff

Comment: That's a fair point, I'd add `[ 'as' => 'todos' ]` as a final parameter on the resource, since its based on the root folder - that way, if they change the routes later, it won't be so many other places to update.